# MobX won't access array value

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm kinda lost with arrays in MobX,

I'm trying to access the value of the arrays and do something with it, but it's acting very weird.

for example :

```
console.log('arr arr', this.props.arr) // ["test1, "test2", "test3"]
console.log('arr arr', Array.isArray(this.props.arr)) // true
console.log('arr arr', this.props.arr.length) // 0 (?!?)
```

So I can't map my arrays, I can't loop over my array, and it's completely useless.

I saw some questions in regard to the same topic handling this problem with `.slice` and `.replace` , but that's not helping either.

if you need me to, I can add the rest of the code

Comment: This is very interesting. Could you please add the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Please post rest of the code as well. Note that in some environments console.log is async, so the length might be null at the moment these statements run, but filled with data when these statements actually print their output.

E.g, if you added the statement at the end: `setImmediate(() => this.props.arr.push("test1", "test2", "test3"))` it could produce the output you see above

Answer (score 0):

This looks like nothing to do with mobx . Mobx just takes care of updating the store . You have to pass the store data in props . Please checked if you have wired the component and store correctly